# PSCredential Where Is ToSecureString?

Tags: c#, powershell, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to run a powershell command as another user in C# using the Runspace Factory. In every example I find there's the suggestion to use `WSManConnectionInfo` and `PSCredential` which requires a "SecureString" for the password. This is the first time I've ever even heard of SecureString.  The usage examples have:

```
var con = new WSManConnectionInfo();
con.Credential = new PSCredential(strDomain + "\\" + strUser, strPW.ToSecureString());
```

There is no string extension method called "ToSecureString" so I'm at a loss here on how to add it. How do I add a ToSecureString method to strings?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.oneget.utility.extensions.stringextensions.tosecurestring(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I saw that but that method is not there in my Visual Studio 2017

Comment: Well, do you have a reference to the assembly it resides in? Microsoft.OneGet.Utility?

Comment: SecureString is a class.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I don't even see that in the list of available references. Is it a NuGet Package?

Comment: There is a reason why converting string to `SecureString` is not easy - storing password as string and then convert it to SecureString at last moment (when you need to use it) defeats whole purpose of SecureString.

Comment: Yeah none of this makes any sense at all, by the time I got SecureString working I realize that con.Credential is read only and none of the examples I saw on this are right.

Comment: It's not readonly, at least in version I tried with.

Comment: It is read only, it won't let me assign anything to it. "Property or indexer 'WSManCOnnectionInfo.Credential' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only."

Comment: `ReadOnly` is an option on the object.. Sounds like you messed up your initialization

Comment: Example? I only initialized it the way I have it in the post above.

Answer (score 5):

That's most likely an extension method defined more or less like this:

```
public static class SecureExtensions
{
    public static SecureString ToSecureString(this string password)
    {
        var secure = new SecureString();

        foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray())
        {
            secure.AppendChar(c);
        }

        return secure;
    }
}
```

As an extra comment: this is anything **but** secure.

Comment: Where do I put this class to make it appear as a method on a string?

Comment: @NathanMcKaskle Anywhere in your project, just ensure you use the same namespace or that you add it to the `using` list.

Comment: @NathanMcKaskle you really should be paying close attention to Camilo's comment about this being **anything but secure**. This is a bad idea; learn about what a secure string is and _why_ it exists.

Comment: The password I'm passing to it is stored in the config with AES encryption, I'm only using this because that's what PSCredential wants it to be.